# Comparing 2 ISO Dates Including Time

Tags: javascript, mongodb

The date is stored in this format in mongo:

```
"createdAt" : ISODate("2017-02-08T18:31:48.646Z")
```

In JS I have two dates for a user and  I want to compare and see if one date is < than the other.  That includes comparing date **and** time.  If the dates are the same but the time on one is more than the other than it should detect that in my comparison.

For example, Here's some React code trying to compare two dates for a user, stored in that kind of format above:

```
console.log('created at date: ' + props.user.createdOn);
        console.log('last login: ' + props.user.lastLoginOn);
        console.log((new Date(props.user.createdOn)) <= (new Date(props.user.lastLoginOn)));
        this.state = {

            isOpen: (new Date(props.user.createdOn).getTime()) <= (new Date(props.user.lastLoginOn).getTime()) ? false : true
        };
```

In the console I see this when the app runs in Chrome:

```
created at date: Tue Feb 14 2017 09:52:45 GMT-0600 (CST)
last login: Tue Feb 14 2017 09:52:45 GMT-0600 (CST)
true
```

Obviously it should be true since the two dates are the same

Comment: They are the same date, and you are comparing if one is bigger than the other one.

Comment: In the ternary operator, you are returning true if the comparison is false.

Comment: why should I compare if bigger if they're the same?

Comment: no you aren't getting it.  That's what I want the outcome to be due to some behavior I need.  I should be getting false if the dates are the same and times are the same and I'm getting true.  So it's not right.

Comment: try comparing with the `.getTime()` method of `Date` objects

Comment: There is also: `Date.compare( Date date1, Date date2 )`

Comment: I've updated my post, check it out.   The problem is when they are equal dates.

Comment: I am using getTime()

Comment: I get Date.compare is not a function

Comment: So if I am reading this right then you are wanting isOpen to be true if lastLoginOn is greater than createdOn? So you comparison should be: `new Date(props.user.lastLoginOn) > new Date(props.user.createdOn)`

Comment: yes if last login is >=

Comment: the problem is I've already tried that, it doesn't take into account time..I need it to take into account time.

Comment: There must be something else going on then because when I run this in [jsbin](https://jsbin.com/geqegeqaci/edit?html,js,console,output) I get the dates comparing correctly including the time. What do the new Dates created from props.user.createdOn and props.user.lastLoginOn look like if you toString them and print them out?